# C#: cannot get listitem field value but works fine in powershell?

Tags: development, workflow, powershell, column, splistitem

back again with a strange issue.
Using powershell I can get a handle on a SPListItem and do Item["My Field"] which prints its value.

However, in a C# custm workflow activity, when I attempt to do this exact same thing on the exact same ListItem I get an error stating: Value does not fall in expected range. I have also tried Item.GetFormattedValue which does not work. I tried the field.title, as well as field.internalname for both methods.

At first I figured the variable I was assigning it to was wrong or that since this particular field was a boolean it could not be converted to a string. (Can't remember which language doesn't allow this). At any rate, I decided to do a dump of all available fields and their values. Turns out, another field of the exact same type (Yes/No) was working 100% fine! Since this is using content types, I also checked to ensure that the field belonged to the content type of the item in question and it does. 
I can't think of any other reason this would happen except that the value was blank. So I unchecked it, still no dice, and re-checked it which didn't work.

Please help!

**EDIT:**
Added code below

```
   #Powershell code that worked
   $web = $site.OpenWeb()
   $itm = $web.getListItem("path to folder")
   Write-Host $itm["DisplayVerboseLogging"] #Yes/No field
   #Outputs correct value - True
   Write-Host $itm["IsDefault"] #Yes/No field (same settings as above)
   #Outputs correct value - True
```

```
   //previously declared string log;
   //Visual Studio (C#)
   SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
   SPListItem item = web.GetListItem("path to folder");

   log += item["DisplayVerboseLogging"].toString();
   //Throws value not in expected range error.

   log += item["IsDefault"].toString();
   //Does not throw exception. log gets proper value - True
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Comment: Added code above @RJCuthbertson